# Searching Patent Applications

Tags: patent-applications

This is a general question regarding patent applications.

I know that these are published weekly and you can search individual patent applications via PAIR. Is there a compiled list of all the applications that have been published for that week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to do your own search.  First, go to the ***[USPTO database of published applications](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.html)***.  Next, enter a search string specifying a start and stop date.  For the week of April 8, 2013 to April 12, 2013, that would look like this:  **PD/4/8/2013->4/12/2013**.  That will give you a listing (in groups of 50) of all of the applications published that week.  If you want to narrow that list down by classification and/or subclassification add the following:  **AND CCL/cla/sub**, where cla is the class code, and, if you want to go to the subclass level, sub is the subclassification code.  For example, CCL/726/35 would be Information Security/Theft Protection.  You can find classification and subclassification codes ***[here](http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/selectnumwithtitle.htm)***.

Answer (score 2):

There is a third-party-site that does offer a RSS feed of weekly updates.

[Freshpatents.com](http://www.freshpatents.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The USPTO publishes the [Patent Gazette](http://www.uspto.gov/news/og/patent_og/index.jsp) every Tuesday. It lists the patents that were issued and lists reexaminations granted, expired patents, etc. However, I do not think it lists published applications.